# How to install OpenGrok on Windows 7 for searching SVN files

Tags: windows-7, opengrok

I am working on Searching through SVN repository.I came through this tool OpenGrok for indexing and searching through the repository. but i problem i am getting is i am not able to get it configured on my system.

Can someone help me in getting this configured or tell me a link which will help me in this.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

does this help?

http://algopadawan.blogspot.com/2012/07/installing-opengrok-on-windows.html

Comment: this seems rather outdated, any updates on this anno 2016?